# Button calls the void starts a coroutine , doesnt run anyting except debug.log in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I made a coroutine that makes the player jump in the game it works when I use the normal "input.getkey" way but when I click a button that calls a void which then starts the coroutine that controls the jump , but it doesn't jump at all the only code it executes in the coroutine is Debug.Log

```
public void ButtonUp()
    {
        if (onGround == true) { Debug.Log("wtf");  StartCoroutine(Jump()); }
    }

    IEnumerator Jump()
    {
        testint++;
        Debug.Log("wtf 2");
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.position += new Vector3(0, .5f, 0 * Time.deltaTime);
        testint++;

        onGround = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.62f);
        onGround = true;
    }
```

yes I know how inefficient my code is.

iv tried the button in playtesting ( I saw that the testint value also doesn't change )  and only debug.log works it also doesn't matter if it's in the first line of the coroutine this is not the only situation the move left and move right buttons also have the same issue for me

( "wtf2" and "wtf1" gets debug into console )

here's the code for the keypress coroutine start

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onGround == true) { StartCoroutine(Jump()); }
```

Unity Version - 2020.3.18f1 Personal* DX11

Comment: Do you have a rigidbody attached to the player? And are there any error messages?

Comment: NVM turns out I am extremely stupid and I had put movement script on the button then executed the script in the button instead of the player